# Are there any bonuses for finishing Flight School?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In [*GTA:SA*](http://gta.wikia.com/Grand_Theft_Auto:_San_Andreas) there was a [*Pilot School*](http://gta.wikia.com/Pilot_School) that would grant you a [*Hunter*](http://gta.wikia.com/Hunter) if you complete all the missions with a gold medal. Does something similar exist in [*GTA V*](http://gta.wikia.com/Grand_Theft_Auto_V)? Or is it there just to learn flying and/or some achievement?

Comment: Well, the flight school *is* the fastest way to get your flight skill to 100%. You can get anyone to 100% just by getting gold on all plane related lessons (no need to do the helicopter or parachute ones). I guess there *might* be a reward for getting gold on *all* lessons, but I don't rightly know, sorry.

Comment: @Nolonar yeah, me neither. Got all gold for airplanes and parachute now, but only silver for both heli missions. Didn't get any reward(or at least it didn't pop up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finished all lessons with Gold medals and did not receive anything...although I still get 3 stars when I enter the airstrip so idk if it glitched and it thinks i didn't complete or what but as of now I have not received anything for getting them all on Gold

You only stop the wanted Level in the airport if one of the character buys a hanger.

Comment: Also got gold on all missions, didn't receive anything either. Haven't checked for the wanted level when entering the airfield but I didn't get any notice and also wouldn't expect to get away with it.

Comment: Anonymous user's comment: "*You only stop the wanted Level in the airport one the character buys a hanger*"